# wlan0 suddenly jumping away from static IP

Tags: raspbian, static-ip

My Pi is set to a static IP. But after a few hours or days it is suddenly no longer reachable on this IP. I now figured out that when this happens the wlan0 interface is no longer on this static IP but on a different one...

This is my interfaces file

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.1.100
gateway 192.168.1.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

This morning it was on `192.168.1.100`, but now it is on `192.168.1.105`. How can this happen?

Comment: I always advise against setting the IP static in the PI, do so in your router if possible. What version of raspbian are you running? I had wifi issues with Wheezy in the past, moving to Jessie has resolved that for me. (Pi2)

Comment: Unfortunately my router does not support static IP... I am on wheezy...

Comment: are you perhaps using the retropie image?

Comment: I am using the wheezy image from raspberrypi.org

Comment: You have both `auto wlan0` and `allow-hotplug wlan0`. Could it be that your usb draw too much power, the usb disconnects (maybe just for a few seconds). Then it falls back to `eth0` which gets a new IP via DHCP. Then you're `wlan0` card comes back up and your connection changes. In other words: 192.168.1.105 is probably `eth0` not `wlan0`. Try `sudo ifconfig` to check

Comment: No, I checked that. eth0 is not connected and ifconfig says wlan0 is on 192.168.1.105

Comment: What does `iface default inet dhcp` stand for? Do I need this?

Comment: Take a look here: https://wiki.debian.org/WPA: "The following line specified in /etc/network/interfaces will activate and configure each 'default' network in wpa_supplicant.conf with DHCP upon a successful connection to an access point". So it look it's your troublemaker.

Comment: So you think I should remove the line `iface default inet dhcp`? Or change it to `iface default inet static` or `iface default inet manual`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"My Pi is set to a static IP" - No it isn't! You have 2 different settings for `wlan0`. It is unpredictable what would happen.

See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697 for a tutorial on how to setup.

Comment: Thank you for the link to your tutorial. But I cannot see why I have two different settings. Because of `manual` and `static`? Can I correct this without changing everything do dhcpcd?

Comment: `iface wlan0 inet manual` and `iface wlan0 inet static`  are attempting to configure wlan0 in different ways. Pick one or the other. If you really want static I recommend the method in the tutorial. If you want to use the older (less robust) method you should disable `dhcpcd` . This is disabled because you invoke `dhcp`.

Comment: I removed `iface wlan0 inet manual`but now I have no more connection. So I will have to try the new method.

Comment: Where do `netmask`, `broadcast` etc. go? Is this not needed here? Compared with the above, is this what I should have in `dhcpcd.conf`? `interface wlan0   static ip_address=192.168.1.100   static routers=192.168.1.2   static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.2`

Comment: @Reto NOTE You should have removed `iface wlan0 inet static` and all reference to `dhcp` (as per the tutotial) NOT `iface wlan0 inet manual`. You have a choice to use `dhcpcd` or not. If not you should disable it.

Comment: @Reto You don't need `netmask` if you use a proper `CIDR` format (as in the tutorial). Note I don't recommend static, don't use it and consider it unnecessary. I use `zero-conf`. The tutorial contains an extract from `man dhcpcd.conf`` which you should read.

Comment: I upgraded to jessie but I do not have dhcpcd. I tried installing it manually but still the service does not exist and the conf file is missing... what can I do?

Comment: @Reto When you say "I upgraded to jessie" did you do a new install? It is not possible to upgrade from Wheezy. Why do you think you don't have `dhcpcd`.

Comment: No, not a new install. I followed one of the many wheezy to jessie upgrade guides.